# DbContext generator or partial class - which to use to modify the default edmx code generated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am new to EF. 
When I used `DbContext Generator`, it created separate partial classes for my entities.
Next I added a property to one of the classes e.g. To the `Users` class I added a `Phone` property

```
 public partial class Users 
 { 
     public int UserId{get; set;} 
     /*new Property*/
     public int Phone{get; set;}
 }
```

But when I update the edmx,  i.e. Update Model from Database, the new property is overwritten.

When I used Partial class instead of the `DbContext Generator`, the new property is not overwritten.

So what is the use of using Dbcontext generator then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you generate your model from an existing database you are using the Database First approache.

If you want the **Phone** property to be created on your **Users** class then you must add a column name **Phone** in the associated table. After that you update your model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if I have a List page where columns from multiple tables are retrieved using join?

Comment: If the result of your request can be mapped to an existing entity then you map  to these entity. If not you can map to a complex type. The Model Designer has a lot of tools to help you doing that.